# How to perform nested loops in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to calculate a count of items where each item may have children whose count will also be included. The tree has no concrete limit as far as depth so I need to be able to loop until no children are found for an item and then go to the next item at that level and continue calculating the sum of the item counts.

I am able to calculate the sum of items at an initial level by using the following SQL but I am at a loss as to how to loop correctly in order to add the quantities for any children of each item:

```
SELECT SUM(ShippingUnitMaterial.Quantity)
       FROM ShippingUnitMaterial
       WHERE ShippingUnitMaterial.ShippingUnitID =                           
             ShippingUnit.ShippingUnitID)
       AS TotalMaterialQty
```

My tables are constructed so a Shipping Unit has an ID and a ParentID. The quantity SUM is calculated as shown in the preceding SUM statement and then I need to perform a lookup and perform the same calculation (added to the main SUM) for each child.

In pseudo-code it would be:

```
LOOP
FOR EACH ShippingUnitID in an input list of ShippingUnitIDs
    SUM the ShippingUnitMaterial.Quantity for all records in ShippingUnitMaterial
    WHERE ShippingUnitMaterial.ShippingUnitID == ShippingUnit.ShippingUnitID
    create a list, ChildList, of all ShippingUnitIDs where the ParentID == ShippingUnit.ShippingUnitID
    IF ChildList is not empty, call MAIN LOOP with the list
END LOOP
```

I can fairly easily write this in C# but I'm having trouble duplicating the logic in SQL.

I should end up with a SUM of all quantities of the tree branches where each branch begins with an ID in the input list.

Sample input List:

```
3093, 3096
```

Sample data for the ShippingUnitMaterial table:

```
ShippingUnitMaterialID  DeliveryID  ShippingUnitID  Quantity
4204                    1           3093            1
4205                    1           3094            2
4207                    3           3099            7
4208                    3           3096            4
```

Sample data for the ShippingUnitSU table:

```
ShippingUnitSUID    DeliveryID  ParentShippingUnitID    ShippingUnitID
205                 2391        3097                    3093
206                 2391        3093                    3094
207                 2391        3093                    3099
208                 2391        3313                    3096
```

The desired output would be:

```
For input 3093, 10
For input 3096, 4
```

Comment: Most likely your best option to write a [(recursive) common table expression (CTE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) But see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results..

Comment: Sample data and expected results added to question...

Comment: Aside: This sounds like a bill-of-materials problem which usually includes propagating quantities as multipliers, e.g. an order for `10` Widgets, each of which contains `2` Base Cycle Croutons, would require `20` BSCs. The child quantities are multiplied by the parent's quantity all the way down the tree. Searching for `[tsql] bill-of-materials` may be helpful.

Comment: The example only has a single level of recursion which can easily be satisfied by a simple sql statement. Is your real-world more complex? If so then as suggested the recursive CTE will be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, what you want here is a Recursive Common Table Expression (rCTE), to recurse through the parent-children relationships and then aggregate afterwards. This results in the below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ShippingUnitMaterial (ShippingUnitMaterialID int,
                                       DeliveryID int,
                                       ShippingUnitID int,
                                       Quantity int);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ShippingUnitSU (ShippingUnitSUID int,
                                 DeliveryID int,
                                 ParentShippingUnitID int,
                                 ShippingUnitID int);

INSERT INTO dbo.ShippingUnitMaterial
VALUES (4204,1,3093,1),
       (4205,1,3094,2),
       (4207,3,3099,7),
       (4208,3,3096,4);

INSERT INTO dbo.ShippingUnitSU
VALUES (205,2391,3097,3093),
       (206,2391,3093,3094),
       (207,2391,3093,3099),
       (208,2391,3313,3096);
GO

WITH Shippings AS (
    SELECT SU.ShippingUnitID AS StartID,
           NULL AS ParentID,
           SU.ShippingUnitID AS ShippingID
    FROM dbo.ShippingUnitSU SU
    WHERE SU.ShippingUnitID IN (3093,3096)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.StartID,
           S.ShippingID AS ParentID,
           SU.ShippingUnitID AS ShippingID
    FROM dbo.ShippingUnitSU SU
         JOIN Shippings S ON SU.ParentShippingUnitID = S.ShippingID)
SELECT S.StartID,
       SUM(UM.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
FROM Shippings S
     JOIN dbo.ShippingUnitMaterial UM ON S.ShippingID = UM.ShippingUnitID
GROUP BY S.StartID;


GO

DROP TABLE dbo.ShippingUnitSU;
DROP TABLE dbo.ShippingUnitMaterial;
```